# Is there a way to automatically publish uploaded assets in AEM DAM?

Tags: aem

We have WebDAV access to our client's AEM Asset Manager and can successfully bulk upload assets. However we then need to go into the AEM authoring environment to publish the assets for use.

This link seems to suggest that auto-publishing can be done using FTP:
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/assets/using/managing-assets-touch-ui.html

Is there a way to set uploaded assets as published without using the AEM authoring environment and preferably through WebDAV (though FTP is not out of the question)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a workflow which gets launched when an asset is created or updated. Using a workflow, you could easily enable/disable the feature if needed with a launcher and also flag the automatically published assets with custom properties, "unpublishing" them if needed just as easy.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will definitely give that a go. I'm fairly new to AEM, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just ask if you need any help. Look into the AEM workflow api and workflow models, how Sling adaptation works and how to mutate JCR nodes.